# Firebase Notification does not show using PHP

Tags: android, firebase, notifications, firebase-cloud-messaging

The response says the notification was successful, but it has not been displayed on my Android phone.

Response:

```
{"multicast_id":6696507350475373329,"success":1,"failure":0,"canonical_ids":0,"results":[{"message_id":"0:1486651908616097%298b4204f9fd7ecd"}]}
```

PHP (src: https://gist.github.com/prime31/5675017)

```
<?php
// API access key from Google API's Console
define( 'API_ACCESS_KEY', ThisIsMyKey);
$registrationIds = array( $_GET['id'] );
// prep the bundle
$msg = array
(
    'message'   => 'TestNachricht',
    'title'     => 'TestTitel',
    'subtitle'  => 'TestSubTitle',
    'vibrate'   => 1,
    'sound'     => 1,
    'priority' => 10,
    'smallIcon' => 'small_icon'
);
$fields = array
(
    'registration_ids'  => $registrationIds,
    'data'          => $msg
);

$headers = array
(
    'Authorization: key=' . API_ACCESS_KEY,
    'Content-Type: application/json'
);

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt( $ch,CURLOPT_URL, 'https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send' );
curl_setopt( $ch,CURLOPT_POST, true );
curl_setopt( $ch,CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers );
curl_setopt( $ch,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true );
curl_setopt( $ch,CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false );
curl_setopt( $ch,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode( $fields ) );
$result = curl_exec($ch );
curl_close( $ch );
echo $result;
```

Android:

I did not add onReceive-Methods because I am able to broadcast notifcations and send notifications to specific devices (RegistrationId) using FireBase Console. All of them are displayed on my device.

```
 private String getRegistrationId() {
        return FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().getToken();
 }

    <service android:name=".MyFirebaseInstanceIdService" android:exported="true">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.firebase.INSTANCE_ID_EVENT"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </service>
    <service android:name=".MyFirebaseMessagingService">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </service>
```

Comment: Hi Dave. Can you also add in your Android side code for receiving the message?

Comment: I edited my post.

Answer (score 2):

When sending push notifications via the Firebase Console, it is classified as a `notification` message payload. By default, Android will handle this message when your app is in background.

In your PHP code, you're sending a `data`-only message payload, which can be handled in Android by implementing `onMessageReceived()`.

If you still prefer not to implement `onMessageReceived()`, you'll have to modify your PHP side code to use a `notification`-only message payload.

Note that the `notification` payload only has predefined parameters that can be used.

More details here:

- https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/concept-options#notifications_and_data_messages
- https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/http-server-ref#downstream-http-messages-json